# Typo3 problem: internal links not rendered correctly after upgrade to 9.5.11

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have just updated my typo3 site from 8.7.29 to 9.5.11 following the official documentation. From technical point of view everything went fine: the upgrade wizard ran successfully in all the required steps and there are no complains from all the available checking tools (database, extensions,...).

The additional problem was that I had to migrate from css_styled_content to fluid_styled_content (because scc_styled_content is not supported anymore by typo3 9). So I modified my old template to work with fluid. After that everything is fine except the fact that all the internal links are not rendered correctly. In particular in the FE all the internal links are reported as:

```
<a class="internal-link" href="t3://page?uid=246" title="Opens internal link in current window">My link</a>
```

So obviously typolinks are not parsed correctly.

Some other users reported a similar problem when the extension frontend editing is used. In my case the problem is still there even if this extension is disabled...

Do you have any idea on what is going on?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: How does your fluid link look like?

Comment: I don't think I have defined one. Should I do so? How?

Comment: How do you define the links? Are you using ckreditor or the TYPO3 build in editor?

Comment: Sorry I thought you was referring to the definition of the function handling typolinks and not just to BE editor. Anyway I have used ckreditor. After having created the link, if see the source the links appear exactly as I have reported in my question above.

Comment: Is the content really rendered by fluid_styled_content, f. e. "lib.content < styles.content.get" and did you include the fluid_styled_content static template?

Comment: Yes for both. By the way I improved a bit the situation. The links are NOT rendered correctly if "Text" CType is used while they are correct for  "Text & Media" or "Text & Images". So a simple (but annoying I would say!) solution would be to switch to "Text & Media" in all the text pages. But is this normal? The fluid documentation reports that "Text" and "Text & Image" have been merged into the new content "Text & Media". So I would expect the upgrade wizard made this modification automatically. Moreover why the old contents are still there and not rendered correctly? I'm confused...